# Qt5 custom context menu ignoring style sheet

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qtstylesheets, qmenu, qstylesheet

I have a two editor classes, say `BaseEditor` and `AdvancedEditor`. `BaseEditor` inherits from `QPlaintTextEdit` and its standard context menu follows my style sheet properly.

My `AdvancedEditor` now inherits from `BaseEditor` and reimplements the method `void showContextMenu(const QPoint &point)` to generate a custom context menu. In it I basically do the following:

```
void AdvancedEditor::showContextMenu(const QPoint &point)
{ 
    QMenu* pStandardMenu = createStandardContextMenu();

    QMenu* pMenu = new QMenu();

    [add various stuff to pMenu]

    connect(pSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString&)), this, SLOT(onContextMenuSelected(const QString&)));

    pMenu->addSeparator();
    pMenu->addActions(pStandardMenu->actions());
    pMenu->exec(mapToGlobal(point));
    delete pMenu;
}
```

This menu however is rendered in the default OS design despite me having the following part in my QSS style sheet (which is properly used for all other menus):

```
QMenu {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4495D1;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

I tried adding a custom `paintEvent()` as described here without any luck: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25664/#117575. Do I need another PE_* type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `pMenu`'s parent widget to the one which has your stylesheet.

Comment: Of course. Really should have realized that on my own. Thanks!